# Java pyramid of numbers - version 2

Tags: java, numbers

I'm reading a book and before I go to next chapter, I want to solve every exercise from current one. I have a problem with creating this output (the number of rows must be between 11 and 20)

[image]

I almost have it, even when I think my code is pretty bad and I could get it in less lines.

```
public class piramide {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int max, n;
    max = 20;
    n=1;
    for (int min=11; min<=max; min++){
        if (n>9) n-=10;
        int x=n-1;
        int x2=n-1;
        int b=min-1;
        for (int j=1; j<min; j++){
            while (b<max-1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                b++;
            }
            System.out.print(x);
            x--;
            if (x<0) x=9;
        }
        System.out.print("A"+n+"A");
        for (int j=1; j<min; j++){
            System.out.print(x2);
            x2--;
            if (x2<0) x2=9;
        }
        System.out.println();
        n+=2;
    }
}
```

}

This is my current code and this is the output:

```
         0987654321A1A0987654321
        21098765432A3A21098765432
       432109876543A5A432109876543
      6543210987654A7A6543210987654
     87654321098765A9A87654321098765
    098765432109876A1A098765432109876
   2109876543210987A3A2109876543210987
  43210987654321098A5A43210987654321098
 654321098765432109A7A654321098765432109
8765432109876543210A9A8765432109876543210
```

The problem I'm having is that the left part of the pyramid should be reversed. For example in the first row it should start at 0 (from the A1A) and finish in 1 but it starts in 1 and finish in 0, any idea how can I turn it to the other side?
Thanks to all of you who helped me ^^.
Oh, and the caps A are just so I could find the number easier in the output.

Comment: For this site, it does not matter whether you're trying to do the homework that someone assigned to you or an exercise from a book. You still need to tell us what exactly you tried and where you ran into a difficulty. The book must have explained something to you before it gave you the exercise, right?

Comment: Where's your code? Where's your attempt? Why do you think that your experience will be any different if you fail to post these things again? Please understand that you're only cheating yourself by posting this without first trying something and then showing us what you've tried for it's in the attempt where you actually learn, and I can personally vouch for this as a self-taught coder myself.

Comment: But obviously I tried, but my problem with this exercise is that I don't know where to start it and can't find anything that help me in that subject in the book, I also haven't any real code of this because I don't know how to start, all I got were stupid int arrays that printed the numbers inside and got the right part of the piramid but starting always in the number 1 instead 1-3-5-7....

Comment: Nothing is obvious unless you show it to us.

Comment: I'll just make some observations that may be relevant.

 - the numbers increment by 1 down the left and right side
 - the number of columns in each row increment by 2 with each additional row
 - the numbers across each row increment by 1 until past the halfway-mark, then decrement by 1... assumably this could be three variables which would run through some loops and print

Comment: BUt the point it's that I haven't anything to show, sorry and I know I suck at this but I started to learn 2 days ago and I haven't anyone who can teach or help me

Comment: You could start by adressing the problem theoritically, see whats the general problem and a way to solve it on paper. After solving it on paper you could start implementing the code. If you have any problem with your theoritical approach or/and later on your implementation, then you should ask a question in so, we would be glad to help you with something more specific.

Comment: What I already learned in the book is the basics of classes and objects, getting user input, declaring and using variables and all the control senteces such as if, for, while... But still on the basics and the subject where this exercise is located is about arrays. I was able to do other exercises but this one got me blocked.

Comment: Still can't solve it but thanks for the help guys, I have to go work now but I'll try again when I'm home again.

Comment: I got this btw http://pastebin.com/GAz4BRpb . And this is the output:
10987654321 
  987654321 
   87654321 
    7654321 
     654321 
      54321 
       4321 
        321 
         21 
          1

Comment: Please post your code and results here with your question as an edit to your question. As has been noted by others, the most important step that you need to do is to break down your big problem into smaller steps. Try to solve the parts that you can solve, and then after that work on the other parts -- divide and conquer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked the problem out?

The code will be much easier to understand with a couple changes...

`max`, `min`, and especially the single letter variables like `n` should have names that help describe what they are. This may also help you think about the problem when you don't have to keep in mind what all those random letters mean.

`n` I will rename to `rowIndex`
`max` I will rename to `totalRows`
`min` I will rename to `columnIndex`

Starting with that we have

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int totalRows = 20;
    int rowIndex = 1;
    int columnIndex = 1;
    //we look ready to start at row 1, column 1!
}
```

Now, this section of your code:

```
    for (int min=11; min<=max; min++){
        if (n>9) n-=10;
        int x=n-1;
        int x2=n-1;
        int b=min-1;
        for (int j=1; j<min; j++){
            while (b<max-1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                b++;
            }
```

You are setting min, *or, the columnIndex*, to start at 11, because that is the "middle" of the pyramid. Then you print out spaces to catch up to the columnIndex.

`x  = rowIndex - 1;`
`x2 = rowIndex - 1;`
`b  = columnIndex - 1;`
`j` and `b` are now like a second and third column index, which is catching up to the actual columnIndex
Look at this example of how your for loop works:

```
for (int j=1; j <min; j++) {   // j = 1;
    while (b<max-1) {          // 10 < 19
        System.out.print(" "); // print space
        b++;                   // b = 11

                               // 11 < 19
                               // print space
                               // b = ...(*skip to the end*) 19

                               // j = 2
                               // b is still 19, doesn't print anything
                               // j = 3, etc.
    }
    System.out.print(x);
    x--;
    if (x<0) x=9;
}
```

In other words, `j` and `b` are unnecessary because we already have a `columnIndex` we can use. Let's do some more renaming of variables.
`x` I will rename to `printValue`
`x2` will be unnecessary, we only need one `printValue`, However, I will be adding a `totalColumns` to the beginning of our `main` method.

So now our finished code will look like:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int totalRows = 20;
    int totalColumns = (totalRows * 2) - 1; //added totalColumns, notice the number of columns increases by two with each row and we start with 1 column.
    int rowIndex = 0;//easier for looping to start with zero
    int columnIndex = 0;
    int printValue = 0;

    while (rowIndex < totalRows) // we will want to spin through every row
    {
        //notice there is no limit to the length of a variable name!
        int numberOfValuesInRow = (rowIndex*2) + 1;
        int numberOfSpacesToOffsetOnEachSide = (totalColumns - numberOfValuesInRow) / 2;

        //Print Spaces before the numbers in this row
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpacesToOffsetOnEachSide; i++) //i is commonly used to stand for index in a single for loop
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
            columnIndex++; //keep track of columnIndex so we know when we are at the middle of the columns
        }

        //Print numbers in this row
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValuesInRow; i++)
        {
            if (columnIndex < (totalColumns/2) + 1) { //depending on columnIndex position, increase or decrease printValue
                printValue++;
            } else {
                printValue--;
            }
            System.out.print(printValue%10); //Print printValue, the % will return the remainder of (printValue/10)
            columnIndex++;
        }

        System.out.println(); //start next line
        columnIndex = 0; //reset columnIndex for the next row
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, now that I see the code I don't know how could I be stucked so much in this problem, sorry I have no reputation to upvote you. And I know I should put more comments and better names to my variables I need to work on that because I always forget about it. Thanks for your help, now I'm going to try to do it from zero again ^^